# Is there any level progression chart for average spell damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

From what I've seen the spells sometimes do quite a lot of damage for their level but at other times they seem to adhere to some sort of rules.

Thus I'm wondering are there some guidelines for spell damage / level for ranged and touch attacks?

Comment: Are you asking about all spells, for all classes, under all circumstances? Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein in essence yes for all classes as I had looked through all and saw the discrepances but also that some spells seemingly adhere to some rules in terms of power level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

There's some fairly comprehensive guidelines for how to make spells in pathfinder [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/magic/designingSpells.html).  Included are a table of guidelines for appropriate damage.

Comment: The interesting part is basically: "A typical damage spell deals 1 die of damage (typically a d6) per caster level for an arcane spell (for example, shocking grasp or fireball), or 1 die of damage (typically a d6, but sometimes a d8) per two caster levels for a divine spell (for example, searing light)."